# ADInterstitialAd iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, ads, iad

I have a general question which I do not understand. I have implemented iAds into my app for the first time. But I also want to implement ADInterstitialAd (fullscreen ads) into my app between different views. But as far I as understood this is not possible for iPhone apps? But I have seen iPhone apps with fullscreen ads between different views. Is this ADInterstitialAd's or something else ? If it is something else, what might it be?

I am greatful for all the explanations, I am 100% new to this area! / Regards

Answer (score 3):

Apple doc says 'Full-Screen Advertisements are Only Available on iPad' https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH5-SW1 
What you saw may be admob Interstitials https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced